# Text of TextInputLayout gets shifted parallel to EditText text

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-textinputlayout

I would like to ask, when i will give left padding to EditText then text of TextInputLayout also get shifted to right parallel to the text of EditText. I want to give padding to EditText only, i want text of TextInputLayout remain at same place(left).

Comment: Posting your layout will help in getting a solution to your problem

Comment: You can create a one layout with TextInputLayout having a EditText.

Answer (score 0):

This is because all the properties(like padding and others) of Edittext are used to decide the TextInputLayout's place in the layout.
You could check TextInputLayout class source code for more details..

In there you will find a method named:
`onLayout(boolean changed, int left, int top, int right, int bottom)`

Method implementation might give you more idea:

```
 @Override
protected void onLayout(boolean changed, int left, int top, int right, int bottom) {
    super.onLayout(changed, left, top, right, bottom);

    if (mEditText != null) {
        final int l = mEditText.getLeft() + mEditText.getCompoundPaddingLeft();
        final int r = mEditText.getRight() - mEditText.getCompoundPaddingRight();

        mCollapsingTextHelper.setExpandedBounds(l,
                mEditText.getTop() + mEditText.getCompoundPaddingTop(),
                r, mEditText.getBottom() - mEditText.getCompoundPaddingBottom());

        // Set the collapsed bounds to be the the full height (minus padding) to match the
        // EditText's editable area
        mCollapsingTextHelper.setCollapsedBounds(l, getPaddingTop(),
                r, bottom - top - getPaddingBottom());

        mCollapsingTextHelper.recalculate();
    }
  }
```

you can see that values of l and r in the method are calculated using `mEdittext.getCompoundPaddingLeft()`(This is nothing but the **paddingLeft** attribute set on Edittext) and `mEdittext.getCompoundPaddingRight()` which are used to decide your textinputlayout's location in the layout

Hope it makes sense!

Comment: Dear friend i need solution. I knew all these explanations, between thanks a lot. Do you have solution?

Comment: @ManikMahendru Well then you need  create you custom TextInputLayout  and  override few methods like above just because you need padding to be different for both of them(Edittext and textinputlayout)..AFAIK It can't be done directly by changing few lines in xml code as you are expecting as answer...And also it doesn't makes sense to go ahead with creating custom TextInputLayout for such smaller case...

Comment: You can't access some methods because they are private and we cant access mCollapsingTextHelper

Comment: Yup I know..but as you can see CollapsingTextHelper class does not extends from any base class but it directly uses android graphics classes and methods to directly implement your textinputlayout layout and animation behaviors which could be well easily implemented inside your app package directly.So, in sense you could create custom TextInputLayout but as said before all those things are not worth the effort for such small use case..

Comment: My friend we can't use CollapsingTextHelper class because this class is 'final'.

Comment: Dude I think you didn't get my earlier comment.. I am not talking about extending it!

Comment: Dude even you can't instantiate it.